# How to display list items on console window in C#?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IList<PersonalDetails> EmpData = new List<PersonalDetails>()
            {
                new PersonalDetails(){ firstName="Alan", lastName="Al", age=25},
                new PersonalDetails(){ firstName="Brian", lastName="Br", age=30},
                new PersonalDetails(){ firstName="Carlie", lastName="Ca", age=35},
                new PersonalDetails(){ firstName="David", lastName="Da", age=40},
                new PersonalDetails(){ firstName="Eddie", lastName="Ed", age=45}
            };
            foreach (PersonalDetails i in EmpData) {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public class PersonalDetails
    {
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This program prints out

```
ConesoleApp1.PersonalDetails
ConesoleApp1.PersonalDetails
ConesoleApp1.PersonalDetails
ConesoleApp1.PersonalDetails
ConesoleApp1.PersonalDetails
```

and I don't understand why it won't print out the data that I put in the list. I've been reading a bunch of posts, but I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated if you can point me in the right direction. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `ToString` method on `PersonalDetails`, otherwise the default `ToString` implementation is gonna be called which prints out the type name.

Add this method to your class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{firstName} {lastName}, {age}";
}
```

You can change the format however you want.

Answer (score 1):

The default string representation for a class is the name of that class.  This is because .NET has *no idea* how you want to print a `PersonDetails`.  You can tell it, though, [by overriding `.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154.aspx):

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0} {1} - {2}", firstName, lastName, age);
    // or however you want to print the values
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Console.WriteLine(i)` is the same as `Console.WriteLine(i.ToString())`. Because you don't have an own ToString implementation, it uses the default one of `Object`.

To fix that, you need to override `Object.ToString()`.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{this.firstName}, {this.lastName}, {age.ToString()}";
}
```

Returning for the 1st object `Alan, Al, 25`

Answer (score 1):

As others have already mentioned, you need to specify ToString method to override it's default implementation. 
In some cases, especially when dealing with dynamic objects, it is helpful to get object string representation by serializing it using JSON serializer (for example Newtonsoft JSON) like this:

```
var objectString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myInstance, Formatting.Indented);
```